# Update RestKit 'lcl_RK.h' file not found in RKLog.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, restkit, cocoapods

I install RestKit v0.25.0 with CocoaPods v0.39 in Xcode 7.1 and have problem with imports. When I used CocoaPods v0.38.2 everything was amazing.
"RKHTTPUtilities.h" file not found. It solves after set recursive in headers search path for "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RestKit".
But I get this error 'lcl_RK.h' file not found in RKLog.h.

I also try do [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/79355#79355).

Comment: Please search for duplicates, this is a known issue with a pending fix. Roll back cocoa pods to 38.2

Comment: @Wain I cann't roll back because  in another project strongly requires 0.39.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found only one not the best way. Add "$(PODS_ROOT)/RestKit/Vendor/LibComponentLogging/Core" in headers search path for project target.

Explain: lcl_RK.h file is in folder path RestKit/Vendor/LibComponentLogging/Core, all other files in folder RestKit/Code/. When CocoaPods generates Headers folder, it misses lcl_RK.h file.

Comment: I've tried everything out there and this is the only solution that actually worked. You saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is having problems with RestKit 0.26.0 and Cocoapods 1.0.1, in a Swift project using Xcode 7.3, hopefully this will help!

This solution worked at least on 2016-06-03, but since it uses specific git branches maybe these will be merged, so if this does not work for you please check if this git branches have been merged/moved/deleted.

## Clean up before everything

Quit Xcode

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf MyApp.xcworkspace  
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

## Use [mcfedr's RestKit fork](https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit/tree/pods1)

Must be used together with "reachablility" branch of AFNetworking

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/AFNetworking.git', :branch => 'reachability'
pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit.git', :branch => 'pods1'
```

## Use module import syntax in Bridging Header

```
@import RestKit;
```

Now it should work!

Comment: This worked for me with xcode 7.3.1 although my project bridging header already had @import RestKit; and so that change was not needed.

Comment: @markhorrocks I think the fork will be merged into development soon, or was just recently merged. So maybe we don't need to specify this fork. wanna give me an upvote? ;)

Comment: I did upvote this answer! I checked RestKit/RestKit just now and it doesn't look merged yet?

Comment: @markhorrocks thx :). Ah I see, It is this Pull Request that will fix it, it is still open though: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/2434