# RestKit loads of errors, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I've installed RestKit using CocoaPods in my new project, to try it out.

I did follow the the steps in https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.

I created the following Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift', '~> 2.1'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'

end
```

It differs in the version of ios from the link, where they used 5.0.

I did `pod install`. All seemed fine:

```
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.6 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (1.3.4)
Using ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.6.1)
Using RKValueTransformers (1.1.3)
Using RestKit (0.24.1)
Using SOCKit (1.1)
Using TransitionKit (2.1.1)
Using UIColor_Hex_Swift (2.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 7 total pods installed.
```

I did start it with `open MyProject.xcworkspace`.

However, I get loads if compile errors:
[image]

Did I miss something obvious?

My git is way over recommended:

```
git --version
git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)
```

Comment: I think you should do 'pod update', not 'install'. Also remove any version specifier. The latest version is 0.26, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do 'pod update', not 'install'. Also remove any version specifier. The latest version is 0.26, btw.

Comment: Ok. I just followed readme. "Install into your project:

$ pod install"

Comment: v0.26.0 is the key piece of information you need, the version of RestKit and the version of CocoaPods need to match as CocoaPods made a breaking change a little while back...

Answer (score 0):

I've got RestKit 0.26.0 to work with Cocoapods 1.0.1, in a Swift project using Xcode 7.3, I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37607556/1311272).

Short version:

## Clean up old pods before everything

## Use [mcfedr's RestKit fork](https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit) with AFNetwork branch

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/AFNetworking.git', :branch => 'reachability'
pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit.git', :branch => 'pods1'
```

## Use module import syntax in Bridging Header

```
@import RestKit;
```

Now it should work